# Xcode goes crazy debugging OSX project

Tags: xcode, macos, gdb

I'm having some issues when debugging my OSX app in Xcode.  After setting a breakpoint I use the gdb console to find values of a variable like:

```
po myTimer
```

This works.  However, I will then terminate the app by hitting the stop button in Xcode.  At this point Xcode goes crazy.  It will usually retype what I put into the console while changing through different windows so that my code gets mangled with a bunch of "po myTimer" kinds of things.  Has anyone else seen this issue?  Is it a known bug?  If so, are there any workarounds?

Comment: I've never experienced that. Are there any warnings in Console that might help you figure out what's going on?

Comment: This might be a red herring.  It appears to only reproduce with a specific project.  It may be a problem with its multi-threading logic.  Unfortunately, the original author is not available to help.

Answer (score -1):

You'll just have to get used to the oddities/crappiness of Xcode, for the most part. Sorry.

Comment: Well, this is kind of an unacceptable one.  Though I guess this means I should file a bug with Apple.

Comment: I actually don't appreciate the negative votes. It's not my software, and people are aware of its inadequacies. Yes, you can file a bug, and sometimes there are fixes. I hope you can find out what it is.